# Separating modal HTML from main HTML

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

What I would like the following code to do is separate rendering of a page and the modals generated within it, the goal is a generic table framework based in Bootstrap in which I can put cells of different types, text, links, or buttons. I populate a basic table in app.py and then have a separate method in the same module I would use to create a modal that would pop up in the same window as the main one. The MWE consists of two functions in the python module and two separate HTML files.

I know it won't work as is because there's nothing to connect to gen_modal, but I'm not sure what I would need to put where to connect this together. Any thoughts?

app.py:

```
@bp.route('/view_table_test')
@login_required
def modal_test():
    columns = [{'name':'column_a', 'display-name':'Column A', 'type':'text'},
               {'name':'column_b', 'display-name':'Column B', 'type':'text'},
               {'name':'column_c', 'display-name':'Column C', 'type':'text'},
               {'name':'column_d', 'display-name':'Column D (Links)', 'type':'link'},
               {'name':'column_e', 'display-name':'Column E (Buttons)', 'type':'button'}]
                                                                 
    data = []
    for i in range(10):
        datum = {}
        datum['column_a'] = {'text':'Text A' + str(i), 'link':None}
        datum['column_b'] = {'text':'Text B' + str(i), 'link':None}
        datum['column_c'] = {'text':'Text C' + str(i), 'link':None}
        datum['column_d'] = {'text':'Link D' + str(i), 'link':'link_a'+str(i)}
        datum['column_e'] = {'text':'Button E' + str(i), 'data-target':'#data_target_'+str(i)}
        data.append(datum)

    return render_template('view_table_test.html',
                           title="View Test Columns",
                           columns=columns,
                           data=data)

@bp.route('/<int:id>/gen_modal', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def gen_modal(id):
    data_target = 'data_target_'+str(id)
    text = 'Modal Panel For ID ' + str(id)
    return render_template('gen_modal.html',
                           data_target=data_target,
                           text=text)
```

view_table_test.html:

```
{% block header %}
<h1>{% block title %}{{ title }}{% endblock %}</h1>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

<table id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      {% for column in columns %}
      <th data-field="{{ column['name'] }}"
          data-filter-control="select"
          data-filter-control-visible="true"
          data-sortable="true">{{ column['display-name'] }}</th>
      {% endfor %}
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {% for row in data %}
    <tr>
      {% for column in columns %}
      {% if column['type']=="link" %}
      <td><a href="{{ row[column['name']]['link'] }}">{{ row[column['name']]['text'] }}</a></td>
      {% elif column['type']=="button" %}
      <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="{{ row[column['name']]['data-target'] }}">{{ row[column['name']]['text'] }}</button></td>
      {% else %}
      <td>{{ row[column['name']]['text'] }}</td>
      {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>

{% endblock %}
```

gen_modal.html:

```
<!doctype html>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="{{ data_target }}" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">{{ text }}</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Modal Stuff</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the visual output.  The buttons don't work.

[image]

Comment: May I ask why you were wanting the modal in a separate file, and not in the same template as your table?

Comment: Well, my goal is to be able to use this template for several use cases. Putting the modal in this template means I have to account for all the ways I might like to use it. I'd like to have it as basically just a generic path to some generic window that happens to be in  a modal.